# How to get an exact number of rows from the temp table?

Tags: sql-server, random, sql-server-2012

I have the query below that runs okay, however at the end of the query when I specify number of rows, I do not get the specific number that I am selecting. Instead, the numbers are either greater or lower. I probably know the cause but do not know how to work around it and get the exact numbers.

```
 `WITH CTE AS
 (
 SELECT  ind_int_code as [Individual Type],
        ind_first_name as [First Name],
        ind_last_name as [Last Name],
        cst_recno as [Member ID],
        cst_eml_address_dn as [Email Address],
        adr_city as City,
        adr_state as [State],
        adr_country as Country,
        cst_org_name_dn as Company,
        cst_ixo_title_dn as [Job Title],
        case
               when mem_member_product like '%Stud%' then 'Associate 
               Student'
               when mem_member_type in ('Associate Corporate','Associate 
               Member') then 'Private Associate'
               When Mem_member_type in ('Associate Under 35 
               Sustaining','Young  Leader Sustaining') Then 'Associate 
               Member Under 35'
            When Mem_member_type = 'Full Under 35 Sustaining ' Then 'Full 
            Member Under 35'
            When Mem_member_type in ('Associate Corporate', 'Associate 
            Member', 
            'Associate Private Member', 'Associate Sustaining', 'Supporting 
            Coordinator', 
           'Sustaining Coordinator') then 'Private Associate'
            When Mem_member_type in ('Full Member', 'Full Member - ULI 
            GreenPrint Center', 'Full Private Member', 'Full Sustaining') 
            Then 'Private Full Member'
        When Mem_member_type in ('Associate Public Agency', 'Associate 
        Public Member') then 'Public Associate'
        When mem_member_type = 'Full Public Agency' then 'Public Full 
   Member'
        Else 'Exclude'
        End as 'Member Type', 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mem_member_type ORDER BY NEWID()) as 
        RN
   FROM co_individual WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN co_individual_ext WITH (NOLOCK)  
    ON ind_cst_key_ext = ind_cst_key 
INNER JOIN co_customer WITH (NOLOCK)  
    ON cst_key = ind_cst_key 
    AND ind_delete_flag=0
    AND ind_deceased_flag=0 
LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_address WITH (NOLOCK)  
    ON cst_cxa_key = cxa_key 
LEFT JOIN co_address WITH (NOLOCK)  
    ON adr_key = cxa_adr_key 
LEFT JOIN vw_client_uli_member_type WITH (NOLOCK)  
    ON cst_key = mem_cst_key 
WHERE mem_member_type IS NOT NULL 
AND adr_country = N'UNITED STATES' 
AND ind_deceased_flag != 1 
AND ind_key_leader_flag_ext != 1 
AND ind_int_code != N'Staff' 
AND ind_int_code != N'Spouse' 
AND ind_int_code != N'Press'
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
where ([Member Type]= 'Private Associate' AND RN <= 3200)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Associate Member Under 35' AND RN <= 1680)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Private Full Member' AND RN <= 1040)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Public Associate' AND RN <= 960)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Associate Student' AND RN <= 640)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Public Full Member' AND RN <= 240)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Full Member Under 35' AND RN <= 80);`
```

Can someone help and fix the query?

Comment: You aren't using a temp table? And you aren't counting the rows? Do you mean you are setting the row numbers and these are not consecutive after you have filtered your Common Table Expression? If so, calculate the row number in the select from the CTE, not in the CTE itself.

Comment: After grouping(using case statements) in my CT table, then at the end of my query I am selecting specific number of rows for each group. But the numbers are off, so I would think that when I do select from my CTE table it doesn't pull correctly.

Comment: Below are number of rows that I want to get, and right after that are numbers that I receive after I run it. Only in one case, I get the exact number of rows returned (250)

Comment: SELECT *
FROM CTE
where ([Member Type]= 'Private Associate' AND RN <= 3200)-4647
OR ([Member Type]= 'Associate Member Under 35' AND RN <= 1680) -685
OR ([Member Type]= 'Private Full Member' AND RN <= 1040)-1986
OR ([Member Type]= 'Public Associate' AND RN <= 960)-962
OR ([Member Type]= 'Associate Student' AND RN <= 640)-64
OR ([Member Type]= 'Public Full Member' AND RN <= 240)-240
OR ([Member Type]= 'Full Member Under 35' AND RN <= 80);-41

Comment: Have you inspected CTE to check it contains what you think it contains? I think you will find that the way it is calculating the row numbers is not how you are expecting it in your query, hence the mismatches in figures you are getting.

Comment: My case statement in CTE table should be okay. When I run simple select queries for each of them. There is always enough rows. What is not correct must be the end query where I pull those specific number of rows because some number is lower or greater that expected.

Comment: You're not pulling a number of rows, you are pulling a row number. You are generating the row number based on mem_member_type, not your case statement, then ordering by NEWID(), so [Member Type]= 'Private Associate' AND RN <= 3200 will only look at the first 3200 rows based on how you have assigned the row number. Are you saying that all your 'Private Associate' records run from RN 1 to 3200? I am not sure they will based off how you have calculated the ROW_NUMBER() - That is what you need to check in your CTE

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the CASE statement for your RN field has carriage returns in it. For example, when the member product is like '%Stud' you're setting the RN value to

```
'Associate (carriage return, tab, tab, tab, tab, space, space) Student'
```

instead of just 'Associate Student'. You can break up the lines on the commas between the string values, but not mid-string like that:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  ind_int_code AS [Individual Type],
            ind_first_name AS [First Name],
            ind_last_name AS [Last Name],
            cst_recno AS [Member ID],
            cst_eml_address_dn AS [Email Address],
            adr_city AS City,
            adr_state AS [State],
            adr_country AS Country,
            cst_org_name_dn AS Company,
            cst_ixo_title_dn AS [Job Title],
                CASE
                    WHEN mem_member_product LIKE '%Stud%' 
                        THEN 'Associate Student'
                    WHEN mem_member_type IN ('Associate Corporate','Associate Member') 
                        THEN 'Private Associate'
                    WHEN Mem_member_type IN ('Associate Under 35 Sustaining','Young  Leader Sustaining') 
                        THEN 'Associate Member Under 35'
                    WHEN Mem_member_type = 'Full Under 35 Sustaining ' 
                        THEN 'Full Member Under 35'
                    WHEN Mem_member_type IN ('Associate Corporate', 'Associate Member', 
                            'Associate Private Member', 'Associate Sustaining', 'Supporting Coordinator', 
                            'Sustaining Coordinator') 
                    THEN 'Private Associate'
                    WHEN Mem_member_type IN ('Full Member', 'Full Member - ULI GreenPrint Center', 'Full Private Member', 'Full Sustaining') 
                        THEN 'Private Full Member'
                    WHEN Mem_member_type IN ('Associate Public Agency', 'Associate Public Member') 
                        THEN 'Public Associate'
                    WHEN mem_member_type = 'Full Public Agency' 
                        THEN 'Public Full Member'
                    ELSE 'Exclude'
                END 
            AS 'Member Type', 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mem_member_type ORDER BY NEWID()) AS 
            RN
        FROM co_individual WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN co_individual_ext WITH (NOLOCK)  
        ON ind_cst_key_ext = ind_cst_key 
    INNER JOIN co_customer WITH (NOLOCK)  
        ON cst_key = ind_cst_key 
        AND ind_delete_flag=0
        AND ind_deceased_flag=0 
    LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_address WITH (NOLOCK)  
        ON cst_cxa_key = cxa_key 
    LEFT JOIN co_address WITH (NOLOCK)  
        ON adr_key = cxa_adr_key 
    LEFT JOIN vw_client_uli_member_type WITH (NOLOCK)  
        ON cst_key = mem_cst_key 
    WHERE mem_member_type IS NOT NULL 
    AND adr_country = N'UNITED STATES' 
    AND ind_deceased_flag != 1 
    AND ind_key_leader_flag_ext != 1 
    AND ind_int_code != N'Staff' 
    AND ind_int_code != N'Spouse' 
    AND ind_int_code != N'Press'
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE ([Member Type]= 'Private Associate' AND RN <= 3200)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Associate Member Under 35' AND RN <= 1680)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Private Full Member' AND RN <= 1040)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Public Associate' AND RN <= 960)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Associate Student' AND RN <= 640)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Public Full Member' AND RN <= 240)
OR ([Member Type]= 'Full Member Under 35' AND RN <= 80);
```